# Как правильно записать значения в новый массив данных из запроса

Tags: mysql, массивы, php, sql

```
for($f=1;$f<count($stud_array)+1;$f++)  
{
    for($t=1;$t<count($work_array)+1;$t++)  { 
        $pos=mysql_query("select `дата` from `посещения` where `фио_студента`='$stud_array[$f]' and `группа`='$gg'  and `дисциплина`='$dd' and `имя_работы`='$work_array[$t]' ");   
        $number_date = mysql_fetch_array($pos);
        $all_date = array();$s = 1;
        do { echo  $number_date['дата'];
            $all_date[$s]=$number_date['дата'];
            $s++;
        }while ($number_date = mysql_fetch_array($pos));}}
        print_r($all_date);
```

`echo  $number_date['дата'];` выводит все даты....

> 2013-06-162013-06-062013-06-122013-06-192013-06-212013-06-072013-06-122013-06-012013-06-062013-06-162013-06-062013-06-122013-06-192013-06-212013-06-072013-06-122013-06-012013-06-062013-06-162013-06-062013-06-122013-06-192013-06-212013-06-072013-06-122013-06-012013-06-06

Однако вывод массива не полный

```
print_r($all_date);
Array ( [1] => 2013-06-06 )
```

Comment: А перевести "ауууу" (желательно поподробней) можно?

Comment: ауууу - есть кто живой?нужна помощь

Comment: [Хороший вопрос - залог хорошего ответа](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_8123.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$all_date = array();
$s = 1;
```

Требуется объявить эти переменные ДО начала объявления циклов for.

Answer (score -1):

Я тоже ничего не понял, но возможно, должно быть

```
for($f=0;$f<count($stud_array);$f++)
```

и т.д. :)